# Web Performance Test with token-based web application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, web-performance

My application separate into 2 part,  webUI (AngularJS) and Web API (ASP.net Web API). After user login, the Web API will generate a token and it will store in browser session storage. Every request must submit this token together to do validation. Unfortunately, the Web performance test not able to read the session storage. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: You can read the headers with new HttpRequestMessage(); method _controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
_controller.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization",this.GetAuthTicket("xyz", "2010"); or something similar in your unit test code

Answer (score 0):

You said the token is generated and stored in the browser session storage, but it is also probably returned in a response. If it is, you can use custom extraction rules in order to pull that token value out, and use it in all subsequent requests in the form of a context parameter. This post may help you out:
[Using custom Extraction Rules](https://ericflemingblog.wordpress.com/2015/08/31/using-extraction-rules-in-your-web-tests/)

If that token is not returned to you in a response of some sort, you'll have to create a custom Request Plugin, and probably tie into the PostRequest event so that you can grab the token it generated. Once you grab the token you'll have to add it to the set of context parameters for the test so that you can reuse the token in all subsequent tests.

If you need to generate a token in the beginning, you may also be able to create a plugin that will generate a token for you, add it to the list of context parameters, and then use that as your token in all headers for each request so the token stays consistent.

[These are some custom request plugins](https://ericflemingblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/helpful-custom-request-plugins-for-web-tests/) I've created before, so they may show you how to get started creating a custom one for yourself.